# Time Difference Calculation in HIVE gives wrong answer

Tags: hive, hql, unix-timestamp

Computing time-difference in HIVE and need it in hours:minutes:seconds. The answer I am getting is not quite right.

This is the query I have tried

```
SELECT from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 12:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 10:10:10'),'hh:mm:ss');
```

The answer I get is 07:49:50

How do I refactor the code so that I have the answer 01:49:50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user2510479

As noted by @mazaneicha from_unixtime function converts to the current system time zone which was causing your result to be `07:49:50` instead of `01:49:50`

To get the expected result (if you prefer to use Hive functions) you can convert from_unixtime output to UTC and use date_format (as of Hive 1.2.0) [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) on it to get desired output

```
SELECT date_format(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime( 
      (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 12:00:00') 
     - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 10:10:10')) ),'EST'), 'HH:mm:ss')
```

You can refer dateformat string in [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: That is perfect!